# Boot problem - /dev/nvme0n1p5 clean xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks

Tags: boot, 19.10, thinkpad

I can't boot my Lenovo Thinkpad T460s. I have a dualboot. I also tried sudo apt-get update, upgrade. I also updated intel drivers via install xvideo-xorg-video-intel.

Comment: Does the Windows Operating system boot up?  Do you have a black and white Grub screen that you can choose what to boot? If you have grub and can choose Ubuntu then do so and hit the Escape ( Esc ) key and see what error it give you.  There may be something simple that stops the boot.

Comment: I am able to boot up Windows easily. When I am in Grub screen and choose Ubuntu I simply cannot boot it up - the statement is /dev/nvme0n1p5 clean xxx/xxx files. xxx/xxx blocks.

Comment: I have just did what you said. Report says that everything is OK, but afterwards I emerge that statement and I cannot boot my Ubuntu. Yesterday I installed Pycharm and did sudo apt-get update && upgrade and I noticed that my Terminal app somehow disappeared. Then I tried to restart the system and got hit by this statement mentioned above.

Comment: Also when I run sudo fsck -f I recieved that /dev/nvme0n1p5 is mounted. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Comment: I have also noticed that my windows operating system is mounted to /boot/efi and that /dev/nvme0n1p5 is my Ubuntu which is mounted just to / (= root) - that could be problem, could'nt be?

Comment: Lastly I tried reinstalling whole Ubuntu 19.10 via USB boot, but the option with "Reinstalling Ubuntu 19.10 while keeping your files, documents, etc" is blocked.

Comment: Wow.  Well done with the troubleshooting.  My guess is that you have a failed/failing hard disk.  You can search the internet about that.  You can try to run one of the fsck commands from a live CD/USB.  Then probably a reinstall. Another thing could be is that your fstab on your install is pointing to the wrong partition.  Have you run Boot-Repair from the USB or DVD?

Comment: I did not do that. I will find some tutorial and try that. Problem is that I cannot access my Ubuntu. I will have to do it in recovery mode.